# bpy.types.Operator meta info based on current Frame

Tags: python

I'm creating a simple add-on that allows you to give each frame a custom description and keywords, which I hope to write to a ***frame_name.txt*** file when the frame is saved.

I've got the basic option set-up working, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the option to reflect the current frame. Ideally, each frame should have a separate value to be input.

So:

**Frame 1:**

- Title: This is frame one.
- Description: This is some guy doing
  something.
- Keywords: Running, Race, etc

**Frame 2:**

- Title: This is frame two.
- Description: This is some guy doing something else.
- Keywords: Jumping, Leaping, etc

I attempted to add custom names to each field using

```
current_frame = bpy.context.scene.frame_current
```

But that does not work since the values are only registered once. 
Perhaps I'm going about it all wrong? Its a simple frame-based information system.

What am I doing wrong to get this input-system **frame-based** and per object?

```
import bpy  
from bpy.types import Operator  
from bpy.props import FloatVectorProperty, FloatProperty, StringProperty   

"""
NOTES
current_frame = bpy.context.scene.frame_current

"""


class PaperDoll(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Sequential Paperdoll Character Class"""

    bl_idname  = "object.paperdoll_operator"
    bl_label   = "Paperdoll Sequence"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER','UNDO','PRESET'}  

    root_title = StringProperty(
        name    = "Title",
        default = "Enter a Title"
        )

    root_description = StringProperty(
        name    = "Description",
        default = "Enter a Description"
        )

    root_keywords = StringProperty(
        name    = "Keywords",
        default = "Enter Keywords"
        ) 

    def execute(self, context, event):  
        print("HERE")
        return {'FINISHED'}    

    def execute(self, context):  
        print("HERE")
        return {'FINISHED'}  

def add_object_button(self, context):  
    self.layout.operator(  
    PaperDoll.bl_idname,  
    text=PaperDoll.__doc__,  
    icon='PLUGIN')  

def register():  
    bpy.utils.register_class(PaperDoll)  
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.append(add_object_button)  

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    register()
```

Answer (score 1):

A StringProperty gives you a single value for the scene, to get a new value for each frame you will need a list or collection to hold all the values for each frame.

Blender does offer a [CollectionProperty](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_72_1/bpy.props.html#collection-example) which should suit your needs. You want to have a value for your string then an index or key that will be the frame that value is good for.